# How to fix "Attempted to load class security.validator.user_password from the global namespace" error in symfony constraint validation

Tags: php, symfony, constraints, symfony-3.4, symfony-security

I am using Symfony `UserPassword` constraint to validate the current password. But it always shows the below error

> Attempted to load class 'security.validator.user_password' from the
> global namespace. Did you forget a 'use' statement?

I am using Symfony 3.4

My validator constraint looks like below

```
Validation::createValidator()->validate($aMyData, new 
    Assert\Collection([
        'current_password'     => [new Assert\NotBlank(), new UserPassword()],
        'new_password'    => [new Assert\NotBlank(), new Assert\Length(['min' => 8, 'max' => 20])],
    ])
);
```

It should validate the current logged-in user's password against the `current_password` value in `$aMyData` array. But it always throws the error.

Additional info

in file, `Symfony\Component\Validator\ConstraintValidatorFactory` have the method `getInstance` which always return the new object of whatever is defined in the `validatedBy` method in constraint class. For "`UserPassword`", validated by is `security.validator.user_password`. Is this correct?

Comment: do you use the standard symfony framework or just some components?

Comment: Standard Symfony framework. FOS User Bundle use the same function in their change password form. This make me think I am using the it in a wrong way.

Comment: for some reason, your security validators apparently don't get loaded. the command `bin/console debug:container security.validator.user_password` will probably also not return a valid object. a workaround would be to add the class manually to services.yaml ...

Comment: Okey. Will try it out. Thank you very much

Answer (score 0):

the `UserPassword` constraint is in the security core namespace. meaning you should add the following use-statements (where `use ... as Assert;` is located in that file)

```
use Symfony\Component\Security\Core\Validator\Constraints\UserPassword;
```

hope that helps

(symfony shows the usage differently: https://symfony.com/doc/current/reference/constraints/UserPassword.html but tbh I don't like the `SecurityAssert\UserPassword` way of writing it ... but maybe you do)

if that still doesn't help (and since the `UserPassword` constraint returns a service name instead of a class name, you might have to actively register that validator as a service (in services.yaml):

```
services: # <-- this should already exist
    # proper indentation!!!
    security.validator.user_password: '@Symfony\Component\Security\Core\Validator\Constraints\UserPasswordValidator'
```

maybe, your FOSUserBundle overrides some of this stuff though ... but it shouldn't.